# Modification of pre-commit hook script

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS=”$1"
TXN=”$2"
# Make sure that the log message contains some text.
SVNLOOK=/usr/local/bin/svnlook
$SVNLOOK log -t “$TXN” “$REPOS” | grep “[A-z a-z]” && exit 0
echo “Please write a log message describing the purpose of your changes and then try c   
ommitting again.” 1>&2
exit 1
```

If I have to track only cpp files from svnlook and throw error if condition fails,what else I should add with this script ? ) grep and find logic doesn't work**

Comment: Is there a typo in your grep?  `grep [A-Za-z]` ?  grep `\w+` would be better I think.

Comment: grep command works fine,...(i mean that grep and find command not working to track cpp files) how to track .cpp files alone from svnlook

Comment: Are you sure that each commit consists only from `.cpp` files or not? What should the script do if there is a mix?

Comment: logic for each commit with only .cpp file ? later i have to think about the mix

Comment: could anyone provide idea for forcing comments only for .cpp files...stuck with this for long days...thanku in advance

Answer (score 0):

So, explain exactly what you want:

1. If all files are `.cpp` files, you want to check the commit comment. Otherwise, you want to ignore the comment.
2. If some of the files are `.cpp` files, you want to check the commit comment. Otherwise, you want to ignore the comment.
3. You only want `.cpp` files in your repository. Nothing else. And, you want to reject any commits that contain non-C++ file.

No matter what you're doing, you'll have to run the `svnlook changed` command and look at all fo the files that have been changed. Remember that there's only a single commit comment for all files committed.

I would be surprised if you're question involves reason #3. C development certainly requires Makefiles on the Unix side, and if you're using a IDE that allows you to specify the build without Makefiles, then there are some sort of *project* files that have to be stored.

You might want to checkout my [kitchen sink pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook). This pre-commit hook will handle almost any situation you want. It uses a control file for configuration, so you don't have to modify the code.

Want to prevent people from anding any non-C++ files?

```
# Remove all permission
[file You don't have permission to add these files to the repository]
match = .*
access = read-only
users = @ALL

# Allow only files ending in .cpp
[file You don't have permission to add these types of files to the repository]
file = **/*.cpp
access = read-write
users = @ALL

# Users must be able to add directories
[file You don't have permission to add these types of files to the repository]
match = /$
access = read-write
users = @ALL

# Probably want to allow the addition of Makefiles too
[file You don't have permission to add these types of files to the repository]
match = [mM]akefile$
access = read-write
users = @ALL
```

Want to make sure the commit comment is valid?

```
[revprop You must add a VALID comment to your commits]
property = svn:log
value = .{10,}
type = regex
```